# Django template won't let my datetime field pop up or open

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I've been experiencing a weird error when using django for loop template, whenever I use my "{% for groups in groups %}" for loop, my datetime field won't open, however when I try to use other context for my loop, it just works. I also just simply copy pasted this modal from my other html page since it has the same function. Already checked if there are any conflicts with id and other loops. Also tried inspecting element on the modal's button, and it shows the correct group id. I have been using the same loop for other functions in this html page and it seems to be working fine as well. Any idea on how to debug this issue?

**admin.html**

```
{% for groups in groups %}
<!--start ALLOCATE MODAL -->
<div id="allocateModal-{{groups.id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
          <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Allocate Device</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h2>Device List</h2>
          <table class="table-width table table-striped jambo_table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width: 10%"></th>
                <th style="width: 30%">Device</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="a-center ">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="routerBox" onchange="enableRQty(this)">
                </td>
                <td>Router</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" id="routerQty" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'mask': '9'" placeholder="0" disabled>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="a-center ">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="switchBox" value="sw" onchange="enableSWQty(this)">
                </td>
                <td>Switch</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" id="switchQty" placeholder="0" disabled class="form-control" data-inputmask="'mask': '9'">
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td class="a-center ">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="terminalBox" value="host" onclick="enableTQty(this)">
                </td>
                <td>Terminal</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" id="terminalQty" placeholder="0" disabled class="form-control" data-inputmask="'mask': '9'">
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="padding-right: 0">
              <label class="control-label col-md-3" style="width: 17%" for="datetimepicker6">Date</label>
              <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="fa fa-calendar-o"></span>
                </span>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <!-- <span class="input-group-addon">to</span> -->
              </div>
            </div>   

            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 0">
              <label class="control-label col-md-3" style="width: 12%" for="datetimepicker7">to</label>
              <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="fa fa-calendar-o"></span>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>              
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Allocate</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end ALLOCATE MODAL -->
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def adminPage(request):
currentUser = request.user

if currentUser.profile.usertype != 'admin':
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/user/")

signupForm = SignUpForm()
newgroupForm = CreateGroupForm()

users = User.objects.all()  
groups = Group.objects.all()
grouptodevice = GroupToDevice.objects.all()
devices = Device.objects.all()

context = {
'groups':groups,
'users':users,
'current_user': currentUser,
'newgroupForm': newgroupForm,
'signupForm' : signupForm,
'grouptodevice' : grouptodevice,
'devices':devices,
}
return render(request, 'admin.html', context)
```

Comment: groups in groups  ???  change to something group in groups

Comment: @vicmathur tried that still didn't work

Comment: change this to allocateModal-{{groups.id}}  to group.id when using group in groups

Comment: you are giving same id (datepicker7 and datepicker6 ) to all elements in groups, So every group in groups have datepicker7 as id and when you click 1 datepicker  multiple id is detected

Comment: @Vicmathur already did, turned it into allocateModal-{{group.id}}, and changed the for loop to {% for group in groups %}, still doesnt work... already double checked all the other for loops i did, and all of them were properly closed with {% endfor %}, I think it has something to do with the queryset Group.objects.all() but have no idea why

Comment: @Vicmathur it is the only datetimepicker id existing in my whole code.

Comment: in UI how many datetime picker you have ?  or  how many groups you have  ?

Comment: @Vicmathur do you mean how many groups i have in the query? I have around 5, it has been working for other functions in the same html, just not for the date. however if i change the forloop to a different query, or if I just even let it have no implemented django code. the datetime opens up :\

Comment: remove id from datetime field (label also) and check if its working

Comment: @vicmathur still wont work

Comment: you are saying its working with {% group in users %}   and others??